# Transferring records between two tables with no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data in a table named `CENSUS` (columns: `APN, ATTRIB_VALUE, ATTNAME`) that needs to be transferred to a table named `PARCEL_ATTR` (columns: `L1_PARCEL_NBR, L1_ATTRIB_VALUE, L1_ATTRIB_NAME`).

`PARCEL_ATTR`'s primary key is two columns `L1_PARCEL_NBR` and `L1_ATTRIB_NAME`.

I have tried to use the following SQL statement to insert records from `CENSUS` into `PARCEL_ATTR` without success:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PARCEL_ATTR (L1_PARCEL_NBR, L1_ATTRIB_VALUE, L1_ATTRIB_NAME) 
    SELECT 
        APN, ATTRIB_VALUE, ATTNAME 
    FROM 
        dbo.CENSUS 
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM PARCEL_ATTR 
                    WHERE CENSUS.APN = PARCEL_ATTR.L1_PARCEL_NBR 
                      AND CENSUS.ATTNAME = PARCEL_ATTR.L1_ATTRIB_NAME);
```

I get this error from SQL Server 2008 R2 every time:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PKparcel_attr'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Parcel_Attr'. The duplicate key value is (002-001-021, Census                        ).

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are only filtering the records which is already present in the `PARCEL_ATTR` table. But you missed to remove the duplicates in `CENSUS` table.

Use `Window Function` to remove duplicates from `CENSUS` table. Try this.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PARCEL_ATTR
            (L1_PARCEL_NBR,
             L1_ATTRIB_VALUE,
             L1_ATTRIB_NAME)
SELECT APN,
       ATTRIB_VALUE,
       ATTNAME
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()OVER (partition BY APN, ATTNAME ORDER BY ATTRIB_VALUE) rn,
               APN,
               ATTRIB_VALUE,
               ATTNAME
        FROM   dbo.CENSUS
        WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                           FROM   PARCEL_ATTR
                           WHERE  CENSUS.APN = PARCEL_ATTR.L1_PARCEL_NBR
                                  AND CENSUS.ATTNAME = PARCEL_ATTR.L1_ATTRIB_NAME))A
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PARCEL_ATTR (L1_PARCEL_NBR, L1_ATTRIB_VALUE, L1_ATTRIB_NAME) 
SELECT CENSUS.APN, CENSUS.ATTRIB_VALUE, CENSUS.ATTNAME 
FROM dbo.CENSUS 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN PARCEL_ATTR AS A 
     ON CENSUS.APN=A.L1_PARCEL_NBR AND CENSUS.ATTNAME=A.L1_ATTRIB_NAME)
WHERE
     A.L1_PARCEL_NBR IS NULL
```

I hope it helps some way.